# create new column based on single value in a record set, inserting the value used into the column

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a query that i have compiled to create a view.

What i am trying to do is use a subquery to extend the view by one column containing a value from one field in each 4 row array/record.

The problem i am having is that only the row with the WHERE reference of the subquery is returning and the other fields in the new column are null.

```
"USERID"
"QID",
"Label",
"Question",
"Answer",
(SELECT DISTINCT "Answer" FROM mdl_questionnaire q
WHERE "QID" = '1234') AS "Emp No Ref" 
FROM(
SELECT 
q.id AS "Questionnaire ID",
q.course AS "Course ID",
c.idnumber AS "Ref Number",
c.fullname AS "Course Name",
q.name AS "Questionnaire Name",
qa.userid AS "User ID",
qa.rid AS "User Response ID",
u.firstname AS "First Name",
u.lastname AS "Last Name",
u.email AS "Email Address",
u.idnumber AS "Emp No Ref",
qrs.question_id AS "QID",
qq.deleted AS "Deleted Question",
qq.position AS "Position",
qq.name AS "Label",
qq.content AS "Question",
qqc.content AS "Answer"
FROM 
mdl_questionnaire q
```

There are more JOINs but not need to be seen for this question

The return i get is this

```
USERID     QID    Label    Question    Answer  Emp No Ref
1          1234   a        Q1          A1      A1
1          2345   b        Q2          A2      NULL
1          3456   c        Q3          A3      NULL
1          4567   d        Q4          A4      NULL
2          1234   a        Q1          A9      A9
2          2345   b        Q2          A8      NULL
2          3456   c        Q3          A7      NULL
2          4567   d        Q4          A6      NULL
```

What i am trying to get is this

```
USERID     QID    Label    Question    Answer  Emp No Ref
1          1234   a        Q1          A1      A1
1          2345   b        Q2          A2      A1
1          3456   c        Q3          A3      A1
1          4567   d        Q4          A4      A1
2          1234   a        Q1          A9      A9
2          2345   b        Q2          A8      A9
2          3456   c        Q3          A7      A9
2          4567   d        Q4          A6      A9
```

The query is for example as my real query is large and would be too much to put on here.

My database is postgres

Thanks

PS  i have searched on here and googled but all i ever seem to find is to use INSERT butim using a view not a table which is not what i want

Comment: Tag properly.  It's either MySQL or Postgres, can't be both.

Comment: Done it was oversight on my part sorry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest to do this in two steps.
First, create a view from your query but leave out the subquery:

```
CREATE VIEW qv AS 
...
"Question",
"Answer"
FROM(
SELECT 
q.id AS "Questionnaire ID",
...
;
```

And then you can run this query:

```
SELECT * from qv JOIN (
   SELECT "USERID", "Answer" AS "Emp No Ref"
   FROM qv WHERE "QID" = '1234') AS foo 
USING ("USERID");
```

to get the desired table.

Comment: Worked like a charm Thank You :)